# Subreport fields empty

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, subreport

I made a subreport to header of 2 other crystal report.
one of the main reports are filled well, but the second remain empty.
I fill the sub in the same way.

```
rowTest("field1") = "123" ' rowTest = dtTest.NewRow
dtTest.Rows.Add(rowTest) 
ds.Tables.Add(dtTest) ' this is the dataset
```

Main report:

```
crTest.SetDataSource(ds) ' in debug I see ds contains all fields
```

Subreport:

```
ds.Tables.Clear() ' clear all the dataSet 
Dim dtTest As New ds.dtTestDataTable ' instanse of data table 
Dim rowTest As DataRow = dtTest.NewRow ' create row
```

I tried to re-import the subReport but nothing happened. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to provide some more information.  How is the sub report linked to the main report?  I am guessing that your children are not in sync with the parents.

Comment: This is the sub: 
`ds.Tables.Clear() ' clear all the dataSet`

  `Dim dtTest As New ds.dtTestDataTable ' instanse of data table`
`Dim rowTest As DataRow = dtTest.NewRow ' create row`, 
The main decleared at the same way

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is in how your report is set up, not in your dataset since you can see that the dataset loads properly.  Check how the subreport is linked to the main report.  In general if its a simple relationship as your describe I find it easier to use groupings instead of sub reports.

Comment: I didn't linked the sub to the main report, but other main report that contains this subreport is working.

Comment: I don't know how a subreport will work without a link.  As an alternative you can use groupings instead of a subreport.  If you use the CR wizard that is the default.